# Hosting ApiControllers on windows service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, service

I have a REST API project with controllers and services behind them, and it works well on IIS.

Now I'm trying to find a way to host it on a non-IIS computer as a windows service. No luck this far, TopShelf seemed to be what I wanted but I have multiple controllers/services to host, and it seems to be able to handle only one at a time.

Is there a way to have a windows service project run another (referenced) project and host it? It's way easier to debug without having the service uninstall-install every time, so ideally the projects would be kept seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host WCF service in windows service. To do that create a windows service project and refer the the WCF project.Also add `System.ServiceModel` and `System.ServiceModel.Description` dlls in in your windows service project then write a function like this

```
private ServiceHost host;

private void HostWcfService()
{
        //Create a URI to serve as the base address
         Uri httpUrl = newUri("http://localhost:1256/MyService/Service");

         //Create ServiceHost
         host = newServiceHost(typeof(MyService.IService), httpUrl);

         //Add a service endpoint
         host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.IService), newWSHttpBinding(), "");

         //Enable metadata exchange
         ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
         smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
         host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

         //Start the Service
         host.Open();

}
```

and call The HostWcfService() in the On OnStart method like this

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (host != null)
            {
                host.Close();
            }
               HostWcfService();

        }
```

and Update OnStop  Method like this

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (host != null)
    {
        host.Close();
        host = null;
    }
}
```